# Spark RDD - which one of the duplicate record distinct operation will pick

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD

```
 JavaPairRDD<String,Customer> RDD1
```

Which has one record

```
cust_id, first_name, lastname
1      "rahul"      "koshaley"
```

and `JavaPairRDD<String,Customer> RDD2`

again which has one record

```
 cust_id , first_name , last_name 
   1        "rahul"          ""
```

when I do union `JavaPairRDD<String,Customer> unionRDD  =  RDD1.union(RDD2);`

The union operation gives me 2 records

```
1)  1 , "rahul" , "koshaley"
2)  1 , "rahul" , ""
```

Now when I do distinct on unionRDD ie

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Customer> distinct = unionRDD.distinct();
```

will the resulting RDD distinct give me output as

```
 1 , "rahul" , "koshaley" or

 1 , "rahul" , ""
```

I want the output RDD to contain the record which has all the values 
`ie 1 , "rahul" , "koshaley"`   !

EDIT -> THIS QUESTION IS NOT DUPLICATE as I NEED TO KNOW WHICH ONE OF THE DUPLICATE RECORDS WILL SPARK PICK AFTER DISTINCT OPERATION.

Comment: distinct look for whole record not single field so there is not duplicate record in your `unionRDD`.

Comment: Its a pair RDD , so I will have to apply reduceByKey in my unionRDD right ?

Comment: I can't see any pairs in the examples you provided. However it depends on input data. How do you handle if there are 3 records and 2 have all the data among them.

Comment: I just edited my question , included pair RDD in my example , now since its a pair how will distinct work , also how to handle the scenario that you explained ?

Comment: Its all depends on your usecase. Im not understanding what you are trying to achieve? Could you explain with concrete example so that SO community can help you quickly!

Comment: Ok i'll edit the question in some time

Comment: Hi can you please help me with this ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783654/how-to-combine-3-pair-rdds